# Roslyn - find all references to method with invocation details (concrete generic arguments)

Tags: c#, generics, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Suppose I have an interface with some generic method, say this one:

```
public interface IService
{
    Task DoGenericAsync<T>();
}
```

Then I have some solution with a bunch of projects and I have the following references:

```
class SomeDomainService
{
    private readonly IService _service;
    
    public Task Process()
        => _service.DoGenericAsync<A>();
}
```

Now the goal is to find all invocations of this method and what is more important - what is the concrete generic argument. In this particular case I want to find that `IService.DoGenericAsync<T>()` was called with generic parameter `<A>`.

So following several tutorials and questions out there, I'm able to find all references to the target method using Roslyn by finding the `ISymbol` of my interface method declaration and then calling `SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync` to get all references.

This works great and I get correct locations of invocations (a collection of `ReferencedSymbol` instances, however the `Definition` property of those results returns me only the general info on the symbol (well, exactly definition :) ), so how do I find out what's the actual arguments were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `ReferenceLocation` has two properties, a `Document` and a `Location`. The document lets you fetch the `SyntaxTree` and `SemanticModel`. When you have the `SyntaxTree`, you can call FindNode and pass in `Location.SourceSpan`, and that should get you the invocation node. From there you can call `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo` and that will give you a struct that contains the method symbol, and from there you can take a look at the type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** Unfortunatelly I haven't finished this pet project yet, but here's the code sample that I composed based on the accepted answer:

```
foreach (var reference in references)
{
    foreach (var location in reference.Locations)
    {
        var syntaxTree = await location.Document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync();
        var root = await syntaxTree.GetRootAsync();
        var syntaxNode = root.FindNode(location.Location.SourceSpan);

        var compilation = compilations.First(x => x.ContainsSyntaxTree(syntaxTree));
        var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);
        var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(syntaxNode);

        var methodSymbol = (symbolInfo.Symbol ?? symbolInfo.CandidateSymbols.First()) as IMethodSymbol;
        var typeSymbol = methodSymbol.TypeArguments.First();
        // then use 'typeSymbol' to find the actual type etc
    }
}
```

In this case, `references` is a collection of `ReferencedSymbol` (the one I'm talking about in the question); and `compilations` - is a collection of `Compilation` for all projects in loaded solution I'm analyzing.